# Multiple targets in a classification problem

Tags: multiclass-classification, softmax, multi-output

I have a vector of length $n \gt 4$ which has exactly 4 targets, so for example `[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]`. I would like to know how I can modify the softmax function for this case. Usually, it is normalized so that all probabilities sum to 1. In my case, all the probabilities will need to sum to 4 -- is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to find a function that "normalizes"/scales every vector to a vector with norm 4?

Usually, you could scale your vector with any feature-scaling method (see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_scaling) for more details).
After you have normalized this simply multiply it with 4 to rescale the normalized vectors.

I hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Wouldn't there be the possibility that the probabilities could be greater than 1 with this scaling?

Comment: could you please specify the requirement you have to the scaling? Sum should be 4 while the individual nodes cant be larger then 1? Also only 4 entries should be non-zero?

If so: just take the four largest entries, set them to 1, everything else to zero.